# Unity how do you change what sprite is displayed on class selection

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a class selection [screen](http://prntscr.com/pv4haa). It works really well and I have the start game button save what class you selected stats.

but how do I put a sprite in the class selection screen of said class( might just use 3-4 old animal sprites at first to get it working then draw ones) then on start game draw that sprite where my wolf is ([image](http://prntscr.com/pv4hx4))

class selection gui code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DisplayerCreatePlayerFunctions
{
    private int classSelection;
    private string[] classSelectionNames = new string[] { "Warrior", "Mage", "Archer", "Priest", "Rogue", "Engineer"};


    public void DisplayClassSelections()
    {
        classSelection = GUI.SelectionGrid(new Rect(50, 50, 450, 115), classSelection, classSelectionNames, 6);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 50, 300, 300), FindClassDescription(classSelection));
        GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 100, 300, 300), FindClassStatValues(classSelection));
        GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 200, 300, 300), FindClassPassive(classSelection));
//GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 200, 300, 300), FindClassSprite(classSelection));

    }

    private string FindClassDescription(int classSelection)
    {
        if(classSelection == 0)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseWarriorClass();
            return tempClass.CharacterClassDescription;
        }else if(classSelection == 1)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseMageClass();
            return tempClass.CharacterClassDescription;
        }else if (classSelection == 2)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseArcherClass();
            return tempClass.CharacterClassDescription;
        }else if (classSelection == 3)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BasePriestClass();
            return tempClass.CharacterClassDescription;
        }else if (classSelection == 4)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseRogueClass();
            return tempClass.CharacterClassDescription;
        }else if (classSelection == 5)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseEngineerClass();
            return tempClass.CharacterClassDescription;
        }

        return "NO CLASS FOUND";

    }

    private string FindClassStatValues(int classSelection)
    {
        if (classSelection == 0)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseWarriorClass();
            string tempStats = "Hp: " + tempClass.HitPoints + "\n" + "Mp: " + tempClass.ManaPoints + "\n" + "Int: " + tempClass.Intellect + "\n" + "Str: " + tempClass.Strength;
            return tempStats;

        }
        if (classSelection == 1)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseMageClass();
            string tempStats = "Hp: " + tempClass.HitPoints + "\n" + "Mp: " + tempClass.ManaPoints + "\n" + "Int: " + tempClass.Intellect + "\n" + "Str: " + tempClass.Strength;
            return tempStats;

        }
        if (classSelection == 2)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseArcherClass();
            string tempStats = "Hp: " + tempClass.HitPoints + "\n" + "Mp: " + tempClass.ManaPoints + "\n" + "Int: " + tempClass.Intellect + "\n" + "Str: " + tempClass.Strength;
            return tempStats;

        }
        if (classSelection == 3)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BasePriestClass();
            string tempStats = "Hp: " + tempClass.HitPoints + "\n" + "Mp: " + tempClass.ManaPoints + "\n" + "Int: " + tempClass.Intellect + "\n" + "Str: " + tempClass.Strength;
            return tempStats;

        }
        if (classSelection == 4)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseRogueClass();
            string tempStats = "Hp: " + tempClass.HitPoints + "\n" + "Mp: " + tempClass.ManaPoints + "\n" + "Int: " + tempClass.Intellect + "\n" + "Str: " + tempClass.Strength;
            return tempStats;

        }
        if (classSelection == 5)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseEngineerClass();
            string tempStats = "Hp: " + tempClass.HitPoints + "\n" + "Mp: " + tempClass.ManaPoints + "\n" + "Int: " + tempClass.Intellect + "\n" + "Str: " + tempClass.Strength;
            return tempStats;

        }
        return "NO STATS FOUND";
    }

    private string FindClassPassive(int classSelection)
    {
        if (classSelection == 0)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseWarriorClass();

            return tempClass.CharacterClassPassive;

        }
        if (classSelection == 1)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseMageClass();

            return tempClass.CharacterClassPassive;

        }
        if (classSelection == 2)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseArcherClass();

            return tempClass.CharacterClassPassive;

        }
        if (classSelection == 3)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BasePriestClass();

            return tempClass.CharacterClassPassive;

        }
        if (classSelection == 4)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseRogueClass();

            return tempClass.CharacterClassPassive;

        }
        if (classSelection == 5)
        {
            BaseCharacterClass tempClass = new BaseEngineerClass();

            return tempClass.CharacterClassPassive;

        }

        return "NO PASSIVE FOUND";
    }



    public void playGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);

    }

    public void DisplayMainItems()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, 20, 250, 100), "CREATE NEW PLAYER");
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(570, 470, 100, 50), "Start Game"))
        {
            playGame();

        }

    }

}
```

I expect on class selection for the displayed sprite to be changed
but at the moment I'm new to this and I am not sure how to accomplish this. its showing my No sprite found else statement but when i try to add code to display the image in the gui it displays a blank space. something like making a currentPlayerSprite variable tied to an location(i have the location in my commented out function) and in a switch statement change what sprite is stored in currentPlayerSprite.

Comment: I figured out i cant use spirite render for the gui one after i save the image after class selection then i can  use spirit render for the first scene. I need a way to show a image on a gui and for it to change depending on what class is selected. something like if (classselection == 0) currentSprite = MageSprite and i would make mage sprite = to what ever you need to display a image in C#. im really new to this now sure how to display a image in a gui

Answer (score 0):

i used this as a function then added one to my list of guis

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 50, 300, 300), FindClassDescription(classSelection));
GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 100, 300, 300), FindClassStatValues(classSelection));
GUI.Label(new Rect(710, 200, 300, 300), FindClassPassive(classSelection));
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(650, 210, 300, 300), FindClassSprite(classSelection));




private Texture2D FindClassSprite(int classSelection)
    {
        mageSprite = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("wolf");
        warriorSprite = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("lizard");


        if (classSelection == 0)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(650, 210, 300, 300), mageSprite);

        }
        if (classSelection == 1)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(650, 210, 300, 300), warriorSprite);

        }
        if (classSelection == 2)
        {


        }
        if (classSelection == 3)
        {


        }
        if (classSelection == 4)
        {


        }
        if (classSelection == 5)
        {


        }


        return Resources.Load<Texture2D>(" ");
    }
```

Worked really well. finally found a good simple way to add a way to change displayed image in a class selection gui. i think sprite render could of worked but i tried alot to get it to work in mine no luck.